# Android: using XML layout from internal storage

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, internal

Stackoverflow has helped me tremendously with my projects. Thank you for that. Now here's my problem:

I've made an app for a company. This company has many customers who will be using the app. The company would like to customize the app layout per customer. They would like to change the background color of elements & button images, among other things.

Now, I'd like to:

- download a customized xml layout from their server
- download customized button images etc.

(Both of these are currently loaded from resources.) Then:

- use those to style the app.

So, the downloading won't be a problem. The storing of the data in the internal storage won't be a problem either. But.

How do I tell the app to use the customized xml layout, which can be found in the internal storage? Up until now I've used this.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now, I want to set do the same, but based on an XML found in internal storage.

In addition, I'd like to load images for buttons etc. from the internal storage too, instead of from resources. Right now I use this:

```
findViewById(R.id.button_x).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button02);
```

So, in short, my question is:

**Is there a way to achieve the functionality of the code above, but with files from the internal storage?**

Answer (score 2):

probably you can create a `XmlPullParser` from the file you downloaded, inflate it through the `XmlPullParser` obect and pass it as paramter to `setContentView`. doc for XmlPullParser is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). The inflate method you should use is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). I have never triedm, but teorically seems possible

Edit:

A project of @RoundSparrowhilltx can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/source/browse/trunk/AnDroidDraw/src/org/droiddraw/android/ViewInflater.java)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seemed like the way to go, until I found this in the docs: "For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime." I expect that would be a problem, no?

Comment: oh my bad. Then the only way to go, I think, is to parse manually the xml and create the hierarchy programmatically.

Comment: If anyone is interested in trying this: there is an open source app AnDroidDraw that has a simple class for starting with.   reference: https://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/source/browse/trunk/AnDroidDraw/src/org/droiddraw/android/ViewInflater.java - I can post a slightly improved one that parses some colors, ImageView placeholders. I'd like to see if someone wants to expand on this.

Comment: @RoundSparrowhilltx thanks for the link. Is that a project of you?

Comment: nope, not my project. I found it after researching here that nobody had found a class yet. It took a lot of search engine crawling to find it ;) Inflating entirely from reading an XML is not very efficient - but this is also the day of quad-core phones ;) My use case is also an activity that never gets destroyed/recreated (it is an always-on floating window, so does not get closed when app closes, nor does it change on rotation).